# Dig command: Is the output guaranteed to be sorted?

Tags: dns, dig

Let's say I'm trying to lookup the IPs `mail.yahoo.com`, `gmail.com` and `mail.google.com`

If I execute:

```
dig @8.8.8.8 +nocomments +noquestion \
    +noauthority +noadditional +nostats +nocmd \
    gmail.com mail.yahoo.com mail.google.com
```

I get:

```
gmail.com.                       299    IN  A       173.194.123.21
gmail.com.                       299    IN  A       173.194.123.22
mail.yahoo.com.                    0    IN  CNAME   login.yahoo.com.
login.yahoo.com.                   0    IN  CNAME   ats.login.lgg1.b.yahoo.com.
ats.login.lgg1.b.yahoo.com.        0    IN  CNAME   ats.member.g02.yahoodns.net.
ats.member.g02.yahoodns.net.       0    IN  CNAME   any-ats.member.a02.yahoodns.net.
any-ats.member.a02.yahoodns.net.  17    IN  A       98.139.21.169
mail.google.com.                   0    IN  CNAME   googlemail.l.google.com.
googlemail.l.google.com.         243    IN  A       173.194.123.21
googlemail.l.google.com.         243    IN  A       173.194.123.22
```

Can I ensure that if I see a `CNAME` record, the `A` record corresponding to it won't appear before a `CNAME` corresponding to another machine or an `A` record for other hostname?

For instance, let me focus on `mail.yahoo.com` (I just want the IP or IPs `mail.yahoo.com` resolves to):

This is the output:

```
mail.yahoo.com.                    0    IN  CNAME   login.yahoo.com.
login.yahoo.com.                   0    IN  CNAME   ats.login.lgg1.b.yahoo.com.
ats.login.lgg1.b.yahoo.com.        0    IN  CNAME   ats.member.g02.yahoodns.net.
ats.member.g02.yahoodns.net.       0    IN  CNAME   any-ats.member.a02.yahoodns.net.
any-ats.member.a02.yahoodns.net.  17    IN  A       98.139.21.169
```

The hostname I'm looking for ( `mail.yahoo.com`) is the first column of the first entry. Then there's a bunch of `CNAMES` I really don't care about, and then an `A` record with the actual IP (which I do care about).

Is there a possibility of getting the `CNAMES` or `A` records out of order? Something like:

```
ats.login.lgg1.b.yahoo.com.        0    IN  CNAME   ats.member.g02.yahoodns.net. #(!)BAD
ats.member.g02.yahoodns.net.       0    IN  CNAME   any-ats.member.a02.yahoodns.net. #(!)BAD
mail.yahoo.com.                    0    IN  CNAME   login.yahoo.com.
login.yahoo.com.                   0    IN  CNAME   ats.login.lgg1.b.yahoo.com.
any-ats.member.a02.yahoodns.net.  17    IN  A       98.139.21.169
```

Or even worse (the actual `A` record on top):

```
any-ats.member.a02.yahoodns.net.  17    IN  A       98.139.21.169
mail.yahoo.com.                    0    IN  CNAME   login.yahoo.com.
login.yahoo.com.                   0    IN  CNAME   ats.login.lgg1.b.yahoo.com.
ats.login.lgg1.b.yahoo.com.        0    IN  CNAME   ats.member.g02.yahoodns.net.
ats.member.g02.yahoodns.net.       0    IN  CNAME   any-ats.member.a02.yahoodns.net.
```

Or the worse of the worse (in a multi-resolution `dig` execution, as the one shown on top of the post):

```
ats.member.g02.yahoodns.net.       0    IN  CNAME   any-ats.member.a02.yahoodns.net.
any-ats.member.a02.yahoodns.net.  17    IN  A       98.139.21.169
mail.google.com.                   0    IN  CNAME   googlemail.l.google.com.  # This one I want
gmail.com.                       299    IN  A       173.194.123.21            # This one I want
gmail.com.                       299    IN  A       173.194.123.22            # This one I want
mail.yahoo.com.                    0    IN  CNAME   login.yahoo.com.          # This one I want
login.yahoo.com.                   0    IN  CNAME   ats.login.lgg1.b.yahoo.com.
ats.login.lgg1.b.yahoo.com.        0    IN  CNAME   ats.member.g02.yahoodns.net.
googlemail.l.google.com.         243    IN  A       173.194.123.21
googlemail.l.google.com.         243    IN  A       173.194.123.22
```

Comment: I'm almost sure dig does NOT guarantee order. When I wrote a nagios test using dig, I had to pipe the output to sort to get it to work properly: https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/blob/master/NAGIOS/bc-services.cfg#L225

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dig` does not reorder the results, it shows them in the order that the nameserver returns them. Nameservers normally shuffle the results (either randomly or round-robin) each time they're queried for a particular record (to implement a simple form of load balancing), although there may be server configuration options that override this. In the case of BIND, the relevant options are [`rrset-order`](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch7/queries.html#rrset-order) and [`sortlist`](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch7/queries.html#sortlist).

As far as I can tell, if you perform multiple queries with a single `dig` invocation, it's as if you had executed `dig` separately for each name, in that order. I can't imagine why the code wouldn't just loop through them in the order they're on the command line.

If the server has to follow `CNAME` records to get the final answer, the [DNS specification](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt) says that each alias will be added to the response in the order they're processed. So you're guaranteed that the original name you gave will be first, and the final results will be last.

Comment: That applies to the results from a single query. The OP is making three completely independant queries on the same command line and wants to know if the results of each query will be shown sequentially.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice that nuance to the question. I've updated the answer with more details about multiple queries and CNAME chains.