# What is the use of sortlist option in /etc/resolv.conf?

Tags: dns, resolv.conf

Was reading man page of `resolv.conf` and meet *sortlist*.

What is the use of it?

Man page shows only list of network\IP addresses after *sortlist* keyword, not the sorting criterion. **How that addresses map to sorting?**

Searched material about this question, did not found answer, though.

Comment: There is no any special sorting criteria. You can define the order from left to right.

Comment: See also: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/165076/117549

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`sortlist` is used to move matching IP addresses in DNS responses to the front of the result list with the intention that applications will use them preferentially. It's a bit obsolete though. Nowadays we have better a standard for that, in the form of [RFC 3484](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3484.txt) (see section 6).

RFC 3484 is much better than the `sortlist` hack better because:

- It supports IPv6 [better].
- It takes source address selection into account.
- It's not specific to DNS (it's hooked into the libc name service, a layer above).
- It's a standard.

RFC 3484 style destination address selection is configured in `/etc/gai.conf`.

Comment: I read sixth section but still have only vague idea about addresses reordering. General idea is understood but practical examples would be very appreciated.
Could you show few example cases of using sortlist option in /etc/resolv.conf?

Comment: @BulatM. I wouldn't recommend using `sortlist` at all today. Back before `/etc/gai.conf` existed, yes, but not anymore. So any example I could show would be better accomplished using `/etc/gai.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

So, to answer your question, 'sortlist' is an options directive for the namespace resolver, the "client" part of an Internet Domain Namespace--the "server" side is the Domain Name Server (DNS).

The *reasoning* behind 'sortlist' is actually quite simple--the resolver, being rather mature code, had no way of ordering responses it issued to queries. For multi-homed hosts--a single hostname having multiple IP addresses--this was sub-optimal. One could find one's self on the slowest or least-reliable interface, rather than the fastest or most-reliable. This was much more important before 1000Base-TX ethernet ruled the universe, but it still has value for a number of network services, and for host administrators.

A 'sortlist' directive set the precedence desired for addresses returned by the resolver (which *is* a C library, btw). The list was a way to control the order of addresses returned for multi-homed hosts. So if one's host had a Serial Line Internet Protocol interface (SLIP) and a 10/100Base-TX ethernet interface, one could set the 'sortlist' to use the ethernet interface in preference to the SLIP interface, *or vice versa*.

That's why the sortlist uses the old-style IP address nomenclature. The resolver uses IP, after all. The explanation in the manual pages is a bit obtuse about that, I'm afraid. By setting a 'sortlist', one is setting the parameters by which the resolver orders the results it returns to prefer a particular network interface, by IP address.

The GAI interface is non-trivial, and you should understand that it is focused on IPv6. One can manage to accomplish the same goals, but using the GAI front end involves a lot more complexity.

On the other hand, using DNS on a Raspberry Pi with Debian is hardly simple. The numerous attempts to "simplify" DNS have created so much abstraction that actually implementing DNS is much more complicated than it needs to be.

To add a 'sortlist' directive to the 'resolv.conf' file on Debian 10u5 (*Buster*, I think?), one must parse the manual page for 'resolvconf' (specifically, *resolvconf(8)*) very carefully. It *should* be possible to set the 'sortlist' in the '/etc/dhcpcd.conf' file, as 'dns-sortlist', but I haven't tried it--I just hack the 'resolv.conf' file (but I have also shut down dnsmasq &c, and I put up with having to re-do the file every so often when the Neworking subsystem feels like being helpful).

A couple of examples for 'sortlist':

*resolv.conf*:
sortlist=192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0
This "tells" the resolver to return the hostname/IP on the 192.168.1.0/24 (that's the old-style subnet mask 255.255.255.0) subnet first; this can help you ensure your workstation uses the ethernet LAN instead of the house wireless, for example.

*resolvconf.conf* (according to the manual page, **but caveat emptor**):
sort_list=192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0 192.168.10.1/255.255.255.0
This is much the same, but directs the resolver to also move any hostname/IP on the 192.168.10.0 network after any on the 192.168.1.0.

interface stanzas in '/etc/network/interfaces' (another caveat emptor)
dns-sortlist=192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0 192.168.10.1/255.255.255.0
This does the same thing as 'resolvconf.conf', only for static interface configuration--so it doesn't work with dhcp.

One ought to note the slightly different nomenclature, because they are different: DNS uses a single word 'sortlist'; the *resolvconf* middleware wants either an underscore for 'resolvconf.conf', or a hyphen for *ifup* in '/etc/network/interfaces'.

From the man pages, it seems likely that the dhcp configuration method--which is the most common nowadays--will require some kind of manual intervention to set the sortlist parameter; probably it can be done in dhclient.conf ('/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf'), but the '/etc/dhcp/dhclient-enter-hooks.d/resolvconf' script does not include any code to extract a sortlist parameter from dhcpcd.conf, nor is there a script in '/etc/dhcp/dhclient-exit-hooks.d/' to do it.